# Using Fody and Ionad to replace static calls on external assemblies

Tags: c#, msbuild, fody, compile-time-weaving

I'm using Fody and Ionad to replace static calls to `DateTime.Now` as it is described in the documentation:

```
[StaticReplacement(typeof(DateTime))]
public static class DateTimeSubstitute
{
    public static IDateTime Current { get; set; }

    public static DateTime Now { get { return Current.Now; } }
}
```

This works fine for assemblies inside my project. However, I have external assemblies that are not referenced directly by my project, and I need to perform the same replacement, but on-demand...

How do I run Fody Ionide for a specific assembly (given a path?)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fody does not currently support execution against non-project dlls. That is, you can only run it from within the current project and target the assembly of that current project